# Acronym or expression that describes the distress over having missed out on something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There's FOMO: *Fear Of Missing Out*.

I'm looking for a similar concept but for the past tense. Some concept/expression/acronym that describes the feeling of distress over having missed out on something.

For example, on the day after a party you decided not to go to, you might realize that the party was amazing.

> "Oh, just found out on Twitter how good the party was. Now I'm feeling
> <concept>."

Another example is if you discover that your friends went to a party you were not invited to.

(So "regret" is not the right word here, since it doesn't apply to the previous example.)

Has something like this already been coined?

After some research I found the following:

[FOHMO](http://www.joepritchard.me.uk/2016/11/fomo-and-fohmo/) (Fear Of Having Missed Out) - It doesn't really describe what I'm looking for since in my case, you don't **fear** that you missed out, you **know** you missed out.

[KIMO](https://seths.blog/2020/07/fomo-and-kimo/) (Knowing I Missed Out) - Closer, but doesn't express the feeling of distress I'm looking for.

Comment: Anxiety usually means fear of unpleasant possibilities, not past actualities. You'd feel disappointment here.

Comment: Good point. Replaced it with "distress" ("disappointment" is not quite what I have in mind, but thanks for the suggestion!)

Comment: That’s called ***regret***

Comment: Informally (BrE), "Now I'm feeling [**gutted**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gutted)."

Comment: "Now I'm feeling regret at having missed out on such a wonderful time."

Comment: I added a new example and a clarification on why "regret" is not what I'm looking for. ;)  

@EdwinAshworth, maybe, good pointer. At first glance the concept I'm talking about is different, but I'll have a better look.

Comment: What wrong with saying *I **had** FOMO*? Why does the past tense have to be embedded into the acronym. The word *fear* does not necessarily mean *terror* or *trepidation*. If I say *I fear you're wrong*, I'm not actually scared of you being wrong …

Comment: I also don't understand the explanation about *regret* being wrong. It certainly seems to apply to the example you don't think it does: A friend went to a party you didn't, and you regret not having gone yourself.

Comment: Your second example is feeling either ***betrayed*** or ***spurned*** depending on whether you’re feeling hurt because the host didn’t invite you or because your friends chose the part over their solidarity with you.  But those are completely different feelings than ***regret***.     When I was in college Stevie Ray Vaughan played a concert on campus but I chose not to go because I had to study.  I really regret that choice now.

Answer (score 0):

FOMO is a commonly used term in trading and investing. It is seen as a negative trait in a trader when they buy solely because of the fear of missing out when stocks are heading skywards.

I coined the acronym DAHMO for the feeling i get when i do a lot of research and arrive at the conclusion that a particular asset is worth backing only to get to the end of that process and then realise the price has already shot up and I have missed the ideal time to get into the trade. DAHMO = Disappointment at having missed out. And I think it exactly fits what you are looking for. :-)

Comment: Sadly, such inventions are out of place on ELU, which looks at standard (commonly recognised, accepted and used) usages. All StackExchange sites, in fact, require answers that are verifiable by peer review.